# Speech to Text recognition : Text Correction and Result Improvisation in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, speech-recognition

How can I achieve below result in Python

**reference text is :** " We wanted people to know that we've got something brand new and essentially this product is uh what we call disruptive changes the way that people interact with technology. "

**Hypothesis text :** " We wanted people to know that how to me where I know and essentially this product is what we call scripted changes the way people are rapid technology. "

I have to consider this both text where reference text will act as ground truth and the hypothesis text is subjected to be modified based on the reference text.

***My final text should look like,***

" We wanted people to know that `how to me where I know` **we've got something brand new** and essentially this product is **uh** what we call `scripted` **disruptive** changes the way **that** people `are rapid` **interact** technology."

I have used `code sample box` here to show that these texts are wrongly inserted and the **Bold** for the text to be inserted based on ground truth. But in a real scenario, I will use red color for the words which are wrongly inserted and green color for the words to be inserted based on ground truth reference.

I tried to write logic by splitting the text into a list of elements and compare each element. but my logic seems not to work for all the sentences as there can be many possible combinations.

Kindly suggest me if there are any libraries I can use to do this task.

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design or research resource.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Levenshtein distance to compare, see something like:

[Levenshtein similarity in Python](https://stackabuse.com/levenshtein-distance-and-text-similarity-in-python/)

```
import numpy as np

def levenshtein(seq1, seq2):
    size_x = len(seq1) + 1
    size_y = len(seq2) + 1
    matrix = np.zeros ((size_x, size_y))
    for x in xrange(size_x):
        matrix [x, 0] = x
    for y in xrange(size_y):
        matrix [0, y] = y

    for x in xrange(1, size_x):
        for y in xrange(1, size_y):
            if seq1[x-1] == seq2[y-1]:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1, y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1, y-1],
                    matrix[x, y-1] + 1
                )
            else:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1,y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1,y-1] + 1,
                    matrix[x,y-1] + 1
                )
    print (matrix)
    return (matrix[size_x - 1, size_y - 1])
```